# Footer element not shown on Android/PhoneGap/KendoUI

Tags: android, cordova, kendo-ui, footer

We're using KendoUI Mobile with PhoneGap.
On some devices or when the application is run from Eclipse debugger and the phone is locked, footer is not shown when the device is unlocked.
After reloading the app footer element is shown correctly.

```
    <div id="xqual" data-role="view" data-title="LOGIN" data-init="initApp" >

        <header data-role="header">
            <div data-role="navbar">
                <span data-role="view-title" ></span>
                <a id="btnRefreshApp" data-align="left" data-role="button" data-click="doReload" data-icon="refresh">RS</a>
            </div>
        </header>

        <ul data-role="listview" data-style="inset" id="loginForm">
            <li>
                <label>ID<input type="text" data-value-update="keyup"  data-bind="value: id"  /></label>
            </li>
            <li>
                <label>Password<input type="password" data-value-update="keyup"  data-bind="value: pwd"  /></label>
            </li>
            <li>
                <label>Remember password<input type="checkbox" data-bind="checked: remember"  /></label>
            </li>
            <li>
                <div style="text-align:center">
                    <a  data-role="button" data-click="doLogin">Login</a>
                </div>
            </li>
        </ul>
        <h1 style="text-align:center" id='message'>Please log in</h1>
        <img id="imgCamera" height="100">
        <footer data-role="footer">
            <div data-role="navbar">
                <a id="btnSettings" data-align="left" data-click="showSettings" data-role="button" >Settings</a>
                <a id="btnExit" data-align="right" data-role="button" data-click="doExit" data-icon="rewind">Exit</a>
            </div>
        </footer>
</div>
```

Does anybody knows the issue or solution? 
We tried also css like this:

```
footer { 
    position:absolute !important; 
    bottom:0  !important; 
    width:100%  !important; 
    height:60px  !important; 
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: y can't u use footer height as 60% instead of 60px same as width??